# How do I save my MVC4 model if I need 2 submit buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to allow the user to move to the next or previous form, I just need to save the model on navigation.  Is there another way to pass back the model to the controller besides using submit?  Since I need to redirect to other possible pages.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your model object in the TempData collection on submit, redirect, then read it back out again.  For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FirstForm(FirstFormModel model) {
    TempData["TempModelStorage"] = model;
    return RedirectToAction("SecondForm");
}

public ActionResult SecondForm() {
    var firstModel = TempData["TempModelStorage"] as FirstFormModel;
    // check for null, use as appropriate, etc.

    return View(...);
}
```

More details here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: In this case it's still using submit though right?  So how would I go backward from SecondForm and go to ThirdForm as well?

Comment: Correct, you'd use the same pattern for each jump.  Each of your steps would check for the TempData entry.  You could make a helper method if you'd like, something like `RedirectWithTempData(url, object data);` or similar.  It does submit back to the server, but it does not save to the database necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You may save the data asynchronously using jQuery ajax on those button click events.

Assuming your View is something like this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Save","Items"))
{
  <div>
    Name :  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
    <input type="button" class="navigBtns" value="Prev" />
    <input type="button" class="navigBtns" value="Next" />
 </div>
}
```

And your script is

```
$(function(){

 $(document).on("click",".navigBtns",function() {
   e.preventDefault();
   var _this=$(this);
   $.post(_this.closest("form").attr("action"), _this.closest("form").serialize(),
                                                                         function(res){
      //check res variable value and do something as needed
      //  (may be redirect to another page /show/hide some widgets)
   });
 });

});
```

Assuming you have an action method called `Save` in your controller to handle the saving part.

Answer (score 0):

Was given a neat article about this.

[MVC Wizard Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-wizard-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-part-1/)

Basically this, you literally pass the name of the html button.

In the view form

```
<input type="submit" name="btnPrev" />
<input type="submit" name="btnNext" />
```

In the Controller 
    Controller

```
    public ActionResult DoStuff(ModelClass mc,string btnPrev,string btnNext)
{
  string actionString = "previousPage";
  if(btnNext != null)
     actionString = "nextPage";


  return RedirectToAction(actionString,"Controller")
}
```